# Why does my Flask-SQLAlchemy update query not change my table content

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm making a flask website, in which I have a SQLite database with a table called mainscreen. On my home screen I have some text which is got from mainscreen - content column. I'm trying to retrieve the data from my textarea in my form which is supposed to update my mainscreen table. Although I'm correctly being redirected to my home.html, I can't see my changes being made, i.e my table is not gettng updated.

---

### MainScreen table structure

---

```
|- mainscreen
    |- id = integer - primary key
    |- content = varchar(1000)
```

---

### Required Code

---

**flaskapp.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, [...]
from flask_login import [...]
from myproject.__init__ import User, MainScreen
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash,check_password_hash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

app = Flask(__name__)


app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = [...]
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), 'data.sqlite'))

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route('/updated', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def change_home():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        new_content = request.form.get('home', False)
        mainContent = MainScreen.query.get(1)
        mainContent.content = new_content
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('home'))

    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))


@app.route('/loggedin', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    [... ...]
    datas = {}
    datas['content'] = onlycontent
    return render_template('loggedin.html', data=datas)
```

**myproject / __init __.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import [...]
from flask_login import UserMixin
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), os.pardir, 'data.sqlite'))


class MainScreen(db.Model, UserMixin):

    __tablename__ = 'mainscreen'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(1000), unique=False, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, id, content):
        self.id = id
        self.content = content

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<MainScreen {self.id} {self.content}>'
```

**loggedin.html**

```
    <form action="{{url_for('change_home')}}" method="get">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="10%">
                    <h4>Home Page</h4>
                </td>

                <td class="padding-right:5%">
                    <textarea name="home" rows="7">{{data['content']}}</textarea>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></input>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
    </form>
```

**home.html**

```
@app.route('/home')
@app.route('/')
def home():
    datas = {}
    MainContent = MainScreen.query.get(1)
    content = MainContent.content
    datas['aboutme'] = content
    return render_template('home.html', data=datas)
```

**pip freeze**

```
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Login==0.5.0
Flask-Migrate==2.5.3
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
SQLAlchemy==1.3.19
SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.33.2
```

---

### Update 1

---

After setting some breakpoints, it appears that my `new_content` variable is not getting the data. It returns `None`. Since my content column is set to NOT NULL, that's probably the reason it's not getting updated. I need to figure out why my `new_content` variable is not retrieving the data

---

### Update 2

---

It seems my variable `mainContent.content` is now getting updated - I had to retrieve the data by putting `home` in double quotes. Now my `db.session.commit()` doesn't seem to be working. From some online research I found that I might have made some errors in the way I'm initializing flask-sqlalchemy, so I've added some more code related to my initialisation. Thank you, your help is appreciated

Comment: It is impossible to guess what went wrong if you just say it does not work. You have to debug it yourself. See what values you have in python, what exactly you are passing to the template and what you see in the template. You should then give us that information, which is relevant, instead of your complete application.

Comment: @zvone I have provided the relevant code. What's going wrong is that my database is not getting updated. I have tried several suggestion, in fact my last line is getting executed correctly, which means my database update statement doesn't have any errors. But my database doesn't change for some reason

Comment: Well, first of all, there is no data base update in the code you provided. At least I don't see it. Secondly, it is not clear whether the problem is only in template, or in python code. That could be discovered by debugging.

Comment: @zvone         ```new_content = request.form.get('home', False)
        mainContent = MainScreen.query.get(1)
        mainContent.content = new_content
        db.session.commit() ```is the update query. I've tried debugging it and couldn't find the issue, hence I brought it to SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because you're sending the data over `GET` -- try `request.args.get("home")` instead and see if that works.

Comment: Try to debug and see if the data is being sent correctly. put `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` after `new_content = request.args.get('home')`  and see the value of `new_content` from the terminal where the development server is running.

Comment: Using `GET` should work. Take a look at the documentation [request.form](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.form) where under  _Changelog_ it says: "Previous to Werkzeug 0.9 this would only contain form data for POST and PUT requests.". In addition, using `request.args` would move away  from form submissions as `request.args` contains "the parsed URL parameters (the part in the URL after the question mark)." ([source](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.args))

Comment: @Mo_-  My page just keeps loading, and I don't see anything meaningful in my terminal

Comment: @rishi can you show the code where you're adding the break point? please try commenting all the code in that method except `new_content = request.form.get('home', False)` and `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` just to check if the data is being received correctly.

Comment: @Mo_- After I commented everything out I see something in my terminal although I'm not sure if it's meaningful - ```flaskapp.py(153)change_home()->None```

Comment: You should see (Pdb) interactive debugger in the terminal where you will be able to inspect your code. Take a look at this short  video on how to use `pdb` https://realpython.com/lessons/getting-started-pdb/

Comment: @Mo_-  My new_content doesn't seem to be accepting the data, it's None. Maybe that's why my database is not getting updated - as It's set to not null

Comment: @rishi okay so it seems like the data might not being sent correctly. Try inspecting the value of `request.form` in the debugger and see what's sent with the form submission. I recommend that you also don't use `GET` for submitting the form.

Comment: @ Mo_- I have switched to ```POST``` and also made it ```request.form.get```. The value I'm getting for ```new_content``` is still ```None```

Comment: @rishi can you please try adding an extra field to the form `<input type="text" name="test" />` and add a breakpoint in the method where you're processing the form and tell me what's the value of `request.form` (not `new_content`)?

Comment: @Mo_- test is returning desired value.

Comment: @Mo_- I realised that when I was getting the value for test I had put it in double quotes, instead of single quotes. I tried it for ```new_content``` and added a breakpoint, it also gives the desired result however my database is still unchanged, it becomes ```None``` again as soon as my home.html is loaded... it seems

Comment: @rishi okay so the issue seems that you need to use `request.form.get("home") or request.form["home"]` with double quotes, right? try to disable the debugger now, submit the form again and see if the data is being saved in the database.

Comment: @Mo_- No it doesn't get saved. I think that's the only issue now. Is my query for updating correct? That's the only way I know

Comment: @rishi the update query seems right (but the column has limit of 1000 characters). Try setting the breakpoint again, run the commands manually and tell me what is the result of `db.session.commit()`.

Comment: @Mo_-  ```db.session.commit()``` is ```None``` but ```mainContent.content``` has a value

Comment: @Mo_- I might be having a similar issue as described here, but I don't see any solution [https://groups.google.com/g/sqlalchemy/c/v8CURVXTkGA?pli=1](https://groups.google.com/g/sqlalchemy/c/v8CURVXTkGA?pli=1)

Comment: @ Mo_- The only problem left is that my `db.session.commit()` is not working. Is there something wrong with my initialisation of sqlalchemy?

Comment: @rishi your db commands to update the `content` column seem correct. Try saving static data in `content` to see if it's a data validation problem. For example: `mainContent = MainScreen.query.get(1); mainContent.content = "test content"; db.session.flush(); db.session.commit()`

Comment: @Mo_-  I tried this as well, I still don't see any change in my database, however I've switched to MySQL using `pymysql` which is working well, however if you have any more suggestions I will be sure to try it out for future viewers of the question. I would like to thank you for your time and I'll upvote your useful comments as well. Thank you again for all your help, I'm sure future viewers might find their error by going through the comments, so I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @Mo_- Please add the useful suggestions from the comments into your answer

Answer (score 1):

You're populating your text area with `data['content']`:

```
<textarea name="home" rows="7">{{data['content']}}</textarea>
```

This should be empty because you don't pass any value in `data['content']` to `render_template`:

```
@app.route('/home')
@app.route('/')
def home():
    datas = {}  # empty dict
    MainContent = MainScreen.query.get(1)
    content = MainContent.content
    datas['aboutme'] = content  # set datas['aboutme'] but not datas['content']
    return render_template('home.html', data=datas)  # pass {'aboutme': content} to Jinja
```

You should either set `datas['content'] = content` in `home()` or access `data['aboutme']` in `loggedin.html`.

Comment: I apologize, I have a ```def login``` function in which I'm setting another dictionary datas in which I've set ```datas['content'] = my content```.. So I don't believe I'm accessing my data incorrectly. I've accessed the data exactly as I have in my home function. I have updated my function

Comment: In order  to  "[...]  store information specific to a user from one request to the next" you would have to use the `session` object (see [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#sessions)). In any case,  by setting `datas = {}` you clear it and delete whatever has been in there before.

Comment: Since my information is being displayed directly from the database, it shouldn't matter that my ```datas``` is getting reset. I'm not able to make any changes to my database, that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

Possible issue is due to that you are not passing `mainContent` to store it.

```py
@app.route('/updated', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def change_home():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        new_content = request.form.get('home', False)
        mainContent = MainScreen.query.get(1)
        mainContent.content = new_content
        db.session.add(mainContent)  # add this line and this should work
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('home'))

    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Also your are trying to access form data in the `GET` method which I think doesn't contain `form` data that is in the front-end.

```py
if request.method == 'GET':
    new_content = request.form.get('home', False)
```

If you need to set some info, you either need to use `POST` to send the form data or you need to store in the `session['<key>']` your expected value.

I hope this will help on finding the issue.